# keras: model.fit_generator throwing error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, generator, training-data, data-generation

## Generator

```
def generator(n_epochs):
    train_dataset_generator = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(train_generator, (tf.float32, tf.float32))    
    train_dataset_generator = train_dataset_generator.repeat(n_epochs)                  
    train_iterator = train_dataset_generator.make_one_shot_iterator()

    while True:        
        train_images, train_label = train_iterator.get_next()        
        yield train_images, train_label
```

## Model

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=(3, 3), filters=64, dtype='float32', input_shape=(120, 120, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=(3, 3), filters=64, use_bias=True, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.05)),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=(3, 3), filters=32, use_bias=True, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.05)),
    #tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=(3, 3), filters=32, use_bias=True, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.05)),
    #tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=(3, 3), filters=16, use_bias=True, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.05)),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),


    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=(3, 3), filters=8, use_bias=True, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.05)),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),        
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, use_bias = True, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.05)),
    tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'),

    #tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='linear', name='fc')
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4), loss='mse', metrics=['mae', 'mse'])  # mean absolute error        
model.summary()
```

## Training

```
batch_size = 32
n_epochs = 10
#num_batches = int(total_items/batch_size)
num_batches = 2000
train_generator_example = generator(n_epochs)
#train_data_generator = my_input_fn(total_items, epochs)
model.fit_generator(train_generator_example, steps_per_epoch=num_batches, epochs=n_epochs, verbose=1)
```

> whenever I am trying to use mode.fit_generator(.....), I am always getting the error:RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it. If I use model.fit(.....) everything is working fine. I don`t understand what is the problem I am facing here.

Comment: You did not mention which tensorflow version you're using, but I am guessing your problem could be with the optimizer function in your compile, could you change it to this and try? `model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4), loss='mse', metrics=['mae', 'mse'])`

Comment: #1. here, I am using tensorflow 1.8 and I am running it in eager execution,  
#2. if I use "model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4), loss='mse', metrics=['mae', 'mse'])". then it gives me an error:
ValueError: Only TF native optimizers are supported in Eager mode.

Comment: hmm, I thought that might be the problem